# android webview = webpage not found = where to add onReceivedError

Tags: javascript, android, webview, error-handling

I m a newbie, please guide me where to add the onReceivedError code.

This is my original code:

My static page directs to my website, if the internet is slow or no network connect, I get a error showing url, I would like to show another html error page, if possible even reload button.

Thanks in advance for guidance.

```
    public class WebActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webcontent);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());    //the lines of code added
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); //same as above

    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

    }

            @Override
            public void onBackPressed() {
                    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                            webView.goBack();
                    } else {
                            super.onBackPressed();
                    }
            }
```

Where to place the below code:  please guide
Or any improvements

```
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView WebResourceRequest WebResourceError) {
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/errorpage.html");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is set in `new WebViewClient()`:

```
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/errorpage.html");
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
    }
 });
```

Now when an error is received, the web view will load that error page.

Comment: Hi, @zed

Where is error handling ?
I mean to say (webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/errorpage.html");)

When error occurs, how to show "errpage.html"

Comment: Thanks a lot bro (ThumbsUp), You made my day.

Comment: plz ck [identifier expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42177674)

Comment: Remove the code you put there and replace it with this one! This one is working.

Comment: your code is working 100%.  I have a question that, will playstore accept my app with your code ?

Comment: Yes sure. When you upload to an app store they cannot see your code.

Comment: No worries. We all start somewhere.